# R using regular expression to look up values in mutate

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I have a reference table which has 2 columns, for example below:

| pattern | name |
| --- | --- |
| a.*b | name 1 |
| c\d{2} | name 2 |

Let's say I have a dataframe with column col like below:

| col |
| --- |
| adb |
| c12 |
| add |

I want to use the pattern and based on the pattern to create another column based on col.

Using above example, the values for the new columns should be c("name 1", "name 2", NA) respectively. I tried to write a loop with string detect like below:

```
regex_map <- function(in_string){
  ref_table <- read_excel("./data/meta_data.xlsx", "mapping_ex") %>% filter(!is.na(pattern))
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(ref_table)){
    r <- ref_table[i,] 
    #print(str(r))
    if(str_detect(tolower(in_string), r$pattern)){
      return(r$name)
    }
  }
  
  return("N/A")
}
```

The function works fine, however, if I put the function as part of mutate, it is extremely slow, probably as expected. I am wondering how to efficiently do this in R? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The function is extremely slow because you are reading the `ref_table` every time you call it. Read the file only once outside the `mutate` and pass it on as a 2nd function `regex_map` argument , `regex_map <- function(in_string, ref_table)`. You can further speed up the loop by having all lower case `in_string<-tolower(in_string)` just once outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is extremely slow because you are reading the `ref_table` every time you call it. Read the file only once outside the `mutate` and pass it on as a 2nd function `regex_map` argument.
You can further speed up the loop by having `in_string` all lower case just once outside the loop.
I am using `base::grep`, not `stringr::str_detect`.

```r
y <- '
col
adb
c12
add'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(y), header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(readxl)
})

regex_map <- function(in_string, ref_table){
  res <- rep("N/A", length(in_string))
  in_string <- tolower(in_string)
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(ref_table))){
    r <- ref_table[i, , drop = FALSE] 
    found <- grep(r$pattern, in_string)
    if(length(found)){
      res[found] <- r$name
    }
  }
  res
}

ref_table_file <- file.path("~", "Temp", "meta_data.xlsx")
ref_table <- read_excel(ref_table_file, "mapping_ex") %>% filter(!is.na(pattern))

df1 %>%
  mutate(clean = regex_map(col, ref_table))
#>   col  clean
#> 1 adb name 1
#> 2 c12 name 2
#> 3 add    N/A
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the solution that I am looking for! Good point that loading meta_data should sit out side :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  pattern = c("a.*b", "c\\d{2}"),
  name = c("name1", "name2")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  col = c("adb", "c12", "add")
)

df2 %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  full_join(df1 %>% rowid_to_column()) %>% 
  mutate(name = if_else(str_detect(col, pattern), name, NA_character_)) %>% 
  select(col, name)

#> Joining, by = "rowid"
#>   col  name
#> 1 adb name1
#> 2 c12 name2
#> 3 add  <NA>
```